# How can I compare two objects when the method only takes one argument?

Tags: c++, class

So for an assignment we need to create a class called Purse that will represent a collection of coins, and add functionality from there. I'm a majority of the way through the assignment, but I've hit a snag on this method

isEqual

This method will determine if two Purse objects are equal. It takes one argument: a Purse object and returns a boolean value. The argument passed to this method is the second Purse object that will be used in the comparison.

Two Purse objects are considered equal if their values are equal.

note that we were provided with the code to main, and had to supply the code for the class and the methods.

The relevant chunk of main looks like this:

```
cout << endl << endl
 << "purse5 == purse6 is " << boolalpha << purse5.isEqual( purse6 ) << noboolalpha << endl
 << "purse5 < purse6 is " << boolalpha << purse5.isLessThan( purse6 ) << noboolalpha << endl
 << "purse5 > purse6 is " << boolalpha << purse5.isGreaterThan( purse6 ) << noboolalpha << endl;
```

Now if the method accepted two arguments I wouldn't have an issue, as I would be able to do something like:

```
bool IsEqual(int x, int y)
{
return (x == y);
}
```

The point is, I'm incredibly lost, I don't know what to do, if anyone could at least point me in the correct direction I'd be incredibly thankful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: When method is declared inside the class, it has access to its members. So you just need the other object of same class, to compare.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a member of `Purse`, you would use it like this:

```
Purse p1, p2;
bool OK = p1.isEqual(p2);
```

The implementation would typically rely on members of both the instance and the argument. For example:

```
class Purse
{
 public:
  explicit Purse(int i) : i_(i) {}
  bool isEqual(const Purse& other) const
  {
    return i_ == other.i_;
  }
 private:
  int i_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Purse class:

```
bool IsEqual(Purse a)
{
    return (*this == a);
}
```

call it:

```
Purse a, b;
bool c = a.IsEqual(b);
```